# Why are same conditions getting different results?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I am solving [question](https://leetcode.com/problems/single-number-ii/description/). and this is the code written by me

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    Solution ()
    {
        ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
        cin.tie(0);
        cout.tie(0);
    }
    int singleNumber(vector<int>& nums) {
        int ans = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 32 ; i++)
        {
            int count = 0 ;
            for(int j = 0 ; j < nums.size() ; j++)
            {
                if((nums[j]&(1<<i))==1) count++;
            }
            if(count%3!=0) ans = ans|(1<<i);
        }
        return ans;
    }
};
```

for input of nums = [2,2,3,2] my output is 1 but expected output is 3.

where as the correct code is as follows

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    Solution ()
    {
        ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
        cin.tie(0);
        cout.tie(0);
    }
    int singleNumber(vector<int>& nums) {
        int ans = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 32 ; i++)
        {
            int count = 0 ;
            for(int j = 0 ; j < nums.size() ; j++)
            {
                if((nums[j]&(1<<i))!=0) count++;
            }
            if(count%3!=0) ans = ans|(1<<i);
        }
        return ans;
    }
};
```

both the code differ in  `if((nums[j]&(1<<i))!=0) count++;` condition only which seem same to me. what am i missing?

Comment: Please don't be drawn into the [cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) of so-called "competition" sites. Your constructor is not needed.

Comment: Consider what happens if `(nums[j]&(1<<i)` gives a result that is some value other than `0` or `1`.   In such cases, your code will not increment `count` but the "correct" code will.   `&` is a bitwise operator, not a boolean one, so is not limited to giving values of `0` or `1`.'

Answer (score 2):

Your condition `(nums[j]&(1<<i))==1` is true only when the value of `(nums[j]&(1<<i))` is `1`.

On the other hand, the condition `(nums[j]&(1<<i))!=0` is true whenever the value of `(nums[j]&(1<<i))` is not `0`.

`(nums[j]&(1<<i))` can be values other than `0` nor `1`. For example, the value is `2` when `nums[j]=3` and `i=1`.

If you want to use `==1`, you can use `((nums[j]>>i)&1)==1`.

Comment: thanks, i just realised that after reading you reply.